# What is HTTP Referer header?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to check this? I'm using the .NET framework and want to understand more on how to protect from CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referrer checking alone [won't help you](http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html#referer) and it can bother users, so it's better not to rely on it.

ASP.NET can help you mitigate CSRFs through [the viewstate](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html): every postback must include the viewstate, otherwise the framework will raise an exception, and since an attacker can't read it (to read the viewstate he must fetch the page, and cross site AJAX requests are not allowed) the attack will fail.

However, as V4Vendetta [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753604/what-is-http-referer-header/5753684#comment-6586815) the viewstate alone [is not enough](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=62): if the page does not contain controls with unique-per-user content the viewstate will be the same for different user, so the attacker can simply submit his viewstate.

To prevent this you can place this code in every page you want to protect:

```
protected void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ViewStateUserKey = this.Session.SessionID;
}
```

Setting the [`Page.ViewStateUserKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.viewstateuserkey.aspx) will create a unique viewstate for every user, defeating the copy/paste. Or you can use a dedicated module like [this](https://anticsrf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Are you sure the viewstate validation stops that ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: The forged form won't have the viewstate field, because you can have it only if you view (or fetch) the page, since cross domain AJAX requests are not allowed, the third party site can't have it, and your page will raise an exception. Obviously, if you disabled the viewstate or the viewstate validation or you're calling an handler or a webservice, you won't be protected.

Comment: You are right but was confused after reading [This](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=62)

Comment: "Referrer checking won't help" this is not true. It won't eliminate CSRF, but if you are concerned about security you should absolutely use referer check too. (Even if at the first glance it may seem to be only a subset of form id's).

Comment: V4Vendetta, I didn't knew that, I've updated the answer accordingly. @vbence: referrer checking is not effective (if it can fail it can't be trusted) and can hinder you're user experience, since more effective measures exists I strongly recommend not to rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can check and deny request from third party sites to the "controller" part of your site (which actually makes changes in the DB).

You have to allow **empty** referers too, because some firewalls and browsers do not send them at all. But it is a must have protection.

In c# you can access it by:

```
MyReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you in dealing/understanding

[Read this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)

It tells for attaching a crypto strong random value and setting it as a cookie on the users machine and include the same as a form value and cookie value. This will help.(SO seems to use this effectively)